# Highlight selected item on GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridView which is showing images from an API. OnClick of the item I want to highlight the image border with some color and on tapping the item again it should return to its previous state. I have created a selector class and tried to set it in a ListSelector but its not working.
Here is my sample code:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/states_grid_view">

</GridView>
```

Selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#3c77d6"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

states_grid_view.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- grid view item pressed state -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        />
    <!-- grid view item selected state -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/selector"
        />
</selector>
```

I just wanted to know what I am doing wrong and also wanted to know how to come to previous state on tapping the item again.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see any error in your code, In fact it is working fine in my machine.
Here is the activity class code.

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_test);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.pulltorefresh_gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample1,
            R.drawable.sample2,
            R.drawable.sample3,
            R.drawable.sample4,
            R.drawable.sample5,
            R.drawable.sample6,
            R.drawable.sample7,
            R.drawable.sample8
    };
}
```

}